# Importing Azure SQL database into Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-sql-database

I am setting up VS 2013 for development with Azure SQL Database (I am new to Azure). I have set up a database on Azure and a Solution on VS 2013. The local machine is Windows 8.1 Pro, with SQL server 2014 Express. I am trying to import the database on Azure into the VS solution. I have changed the Target platform on VS to “Microsoft Azure SQL Database”. I have checked that VS can see the Azure database by using “Test Connection” – all appears well.

When I start the Import Database, I get the following error:

> You cannot import a 1025 database because you project’s target platform is set to 130. To learn more about changing your target platform and/or source database, or the supported database editions for specific target platforms, please refer to Import Schema help page.

I cannot find the help referred to in the error message. I have tried changing the target to SQL server 2014, no joy. Can anyone give me some pointers?

Answer (score 1):

This issue could be SSDT version issue. Can you download and install the latest RTM or Preview version of SSDT from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx

If you need to try out all GA and Preview features of Azure SQL DB, SSDT Preview would cover it. Otherwise SSDT RTM version will provide the stability.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I downloaded VS 2013 and SSDT the day I logged the question. I believe I am using the latest release of SQL Server 2014 Express.

Answer (score 1):

For this:

1. Created the SQL project
2. Set target to Azure SQL
3. Instead of "Import" did "Synchronize"

Answer (score 0):

The numbers refer to they type of sql installation, with 130 being 2014, and 1025 being the azure cloud. Exporting data from azure is a little more complicated than you would expect with a VM, because of the way SQL Azure works behind the scenes. First to literally answer your question [here is the link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh335292.aspx) to how to use the import export services so you can get the DB on your local 2014 install. However I imagine what you want to do is actually develop for that server without some painful import export process, which is why I think this [link that talks about what tools to use](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee621784.aspx) might be more helpful.

Anyway, good luck, SQL azure is very much a product in it's infancy.

Comment: Thanks Randall. I have bought a book (Step by Step Microsoft Azure SQL Database) which unfortunately is a little obsolete - Azure has been updated... It proposes setting up a solution on a local PC and then sending it to the Cloud on release - sounds the way to go but I fell very early. I will try reading how VS recommend working with Azure.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around the problem by working from VS 2013 and creating the Db in VS and publishing to Azure following the tutorial:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-get-started/

I hope I will not need to import a Db in the future!

Thank you to all those that edited & answered. I hope to be able to return the favour.

Answer (score 0):

Importing from Azure into a Sql Server Project works in Visual Studio 2015 with no issues.